# How to launch the incoming call interface?

Tags: android, sip

I'm devlopping a SIP application and whant to launch the normal incoming call interface when having an incoming call from a SIP client. Is that possible ?
Thank you very much.

Comment: I do not think it is possible, but I can investigate if you are still interested in that answer.

Comment: @Zelimir: Yes please try to help me, i'm always intrested in that.

Comment: I am interested as well so I will try to collect some useful info.

Comment: @Zelimir: Yes please if you found something just notice me(I'm using now an ungly AlertDialog :D). Thank you very much.

Comment: @Zelimir: I hope that you found something interesting :P .

Comment: Beter ever than never, or not? Sorry for big delay, but now I know the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sorry, but it looks like there is nothing as standard incoming call interface in Android (at least not until API level 10).

The screen that you see on incoming call is part of the native PhoneApp. More specifically, it is handled by the class InCallScreen.java from the dialer source code. That Activity has no Intent filters defined, so definitely it is not intended for external usage.

However, some applications may mimic native screens (or copy complete layout, not sure if license allows that), so it looks like it is from native, although in fact it is not.

Comment: Thanks for answering! It was a long time ago :D! Anyway, now i know the correct answer. Thank you very much dude.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the source of default phone app, and I figured the only way to get this done is draw a layout exactly like the default incoming call interface  -_-||
If you have the solution , please tell me , thank you so much !

Comment: We can't launch the default incoming call interface :/