# how to get incoming call alert dialog on main or home screen in SIP application?

Tags: android, sip, android-alertdialog

I am developing the SIP application for call and i have used **AlertDialog** for incoming call notification but its not feasible because when application is running on the background and someone calls, the "call screen" isn't been launched.what should i do? should i create a new screen for that or i can use the native incoming call screen? if you have idea about this please let me know. thanks in advance. Related this question:[see this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918710/how-to-launch-the-incoming-call-interface/9732678#comment12377740_9732678).

Answer (score 1):

You should register the intent filter with a [service](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html) and then launch the activity with the AlertDialog style form the service.

Comment: can you explain me in detail how do i achieve this task? i have used FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK and it opens the dialog while application is on background but the problem is when i am clicking on any button either accept or reject the application is crashes. please see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766679/application-crashes-while-using-a-method-of-different-class)

Comment: Can you post the crash? Thanks

Comment: java.lang.Nullpointerexception
com.example.android.sip.IncomingCallReceiver.acceptCall(IncomingCallReceiver.java:123)
com.example.android.sip.IncomingCallPage$1.onClick(IncomingCallPage.java:31)
com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:159)
android .os.handler.dispatchmessage(Handler)
android .os.looper.loop.java:123
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.example.android.sip.IncomingCallReceiver

Comment: @ pablisco to verify the code please see the link which i have mentioned in first comment. thanks

Comment: Well, that's a NullPointerException. One of the easier exceptions to fix. It means that the app is trying to access a pointer that has no memory address assigned to it. Try entering the `acceptCall()` method from debug mode on Eclipse and see what it is that is null.

Comment: yeah you are right. Actually the code for acceptCall() method is written in incomingCallReciever.java file and i am accessing this method in incomingCallpage.java. if i am calling this acceptCall() method in incomingCallreciver.java then it works properly rather then it gives me nullpointer exception.

Comment: even i dont know how to enter the method from debug mode on eclipse.

Comment: i tried with this. i am getting the listener as a null which receives the incoming call.this is happens because i am moving to different activity on this page all value becomes null and i am getting this NullpointerException.so the problem is context only.what is the solution of this problem? why that values becomes null when i am calling that method from another class?

Comment: I think you are not using the BroadCastReceiver correctly. Have a look at this tutorial: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidServices/article.html Saying that I am not going to post any more comments since this is not a chat. Good luck.